# i cant write CSS margins in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, margins

im new at visual studio code and going to learning html and css , im at learning using margins then i noticed that i cant write margin in visual studio code in file css. here my example code:

```css
.headerContainer{
    background-color: red;
    width: 40%
    margin:auto
}
```

it keep give me error semi-colon expected css(css-semicolonexpected)

i hope there something i need to change at visual studio code

Answer (score 5):

the error is in your code not in vs code

```
.headerContainer{ background-color: red; width: 40%; margin:auto; }
```

you haven't added semi colon on the width and margin property
in css every property should end with semi colon